# why temporary tables are better in performance then the normal table even though they are stored in different db i.e; tempdb

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

When we use temporary table it gets created in another database tempdb which is a performance overhead. But if we create normal table in stored procedure in place of temp table then it will get created in its own database.

So my question is why we use temp tables in procedure?

Is that due to only the scope of the tables?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server

Comment: Have a look at [Temporary Tables in Stored Procedures](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/15/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps the thing to understand regarding your initial concern about temp tables being created in tempdb is that tempdb is intended to be a high performance area that SQL server uses for internal objects, intermediate results... and temporary user objects like temp tables (and table variables).  Unless the DBA has botched the job of setting up the DB server, temp tables being created in tempdb actually means they will perform better (minimal logging, minimal locking, better cache use for the type of operations a temp table is meant for.... ie. **less** overhead).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use temp tables<sup>1</sup> where we want to store a set of rows and work with them but do not want to interfere with any other instance of the same piece of code, running on a different connection.

If we worked with permanent tables, we'd have to do extra work to prevent interference (such as always filtering on `@@SPID`) or have to restrict our code to only being executed by a single connection at a time.

We also benefit from automatic clean up when the temp table falls out of scope.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or table variables. They're much the same, just with different scoping rules.

Answer (score 1):

Any performance difference between creating a temporary table and creating the same table as a regular (not temporary) table is negligible.  In fact, I would expect to see temp tables perform better as they are treated much like table variables (cache use, miminal locking output).  For a really good discussion on temporary tables, I would go [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385).  That article is a brilliant comparison between temp tables and table variables, which is very enlightening if you want to learn about temp tables and how they are handled.

Comment: This may or may not be true depending on the hardware configuration and the table spaces assigned to the databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - your comment would be true even if I were to say that table variables perform better than normal tables (within their intended purpose).  With the right (or rather wrong) hardware configuration and table space allocation, they would not.  But generally speaking, and within the intended purpose of table variables, they perform better.  Temp tables, generally speaking and within the intended purpose of temp tables, stand somewhere in between a normal table and a table variable, as far as performance.

Comment: . . Your answer is predominantly about *temporary tables* and *permanent tables*, not about table variables versus temporary tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - My answer mentioned temp tables in all four sentences, table variables in two of them, and normal tables in one.  I was trying to correlate all three.  Assuming the OP knows that generally table variables perform better (within their intended use and assuming the DBA did not botch the server setup), I figured knowing that temp tables are treated much like table variables (including the fact that **both** are stored in tempdb) would help dispel his concerns about their performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of reasons to use temporary or variable tables:

1. They only exist in the scope of the current query.
2. They are stored in tempdb; which, depending on your hardware configuration, is on a faster drive.

My preference for anything other than small data-sets would be to use a temporary table over a variable table because:

1. You have more freedom with indexes on a temporary table.
2. SQL Server Query Optimizer typically assumes that a variable table only contains 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

The prime this benifit is the simplicity in programming and managing.
As you need not to code any thing to create the temp table, you can directly select into .... #tbl,

Secondly Dynamic isolation to the session, you need not to do any thing for session sharing avoidance. let say if same SP runs from two different session two isolated instance of the table would be created.
Run the following code from 1 Query pad (management studio)

SELECT 'ASP.Net' subject INTO #test
SELECT * FROM #test

and from other,

SELECT 'C #' subject INTO #test
SELECT * FROM #test

would create two different instance of the table with table name not just #test but some thing like

## test__________________________________000000000EEC

## test__________________________________000000000EEE

now run the following query to realize it

```
USE TEMPDB
```

SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '#test%';

and

Further more clean up process is also taken care by Database.

Thanks and Regards,

Rk_Hirpara